# Test Cases: Need to figure out how to make two test cases that test my methods that round double(s)

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying to make a test case that enables me to check if my methods work. One method accepts  a double and converts it into a string that is rounded to two decimal places and the other rounds the double to a whole number. If anyone has any advice or can help me out please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using JUnit? Then please have a look over here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/#Getting

Answer (score 2):

I can see more than one test case;

- Round an integer to two places, checking that the two decimals are there and have value "00".
- Round an integer to two places, checking that the decimal symbol is correct for the locale you're testing.
- Round an integer + 0.005 to two decimal places, checking that it rounds the correct way (up/down/bankers/toward even/...)
- Round an integer + 0.015 to two decimal places, checking that it rounds the correct way (up/down/bankers/toward/even/...)
- Round an integer + 0.5 to an integer, checking the rounding direction.
- ...

You get the geist of it, if you *really* want to test, you don't just use *one* test "just to have done it".

Think of all the corner cases and test **them**.

Comment: To the person who answered above... That was completely irrelevant to my question. If I knew how to test it one way I would be able to figure it out 12343434 ways like you suggested. Might help if I knew how to test my method ONE WAY before I tested it 12132342342334 ways. I'm new to the language and just a college student trying to figure things out. I'm not the kind of person who does things "just to have done it" so I don't really appreciate that comment at all.

Comment: @user1725743 Apologies if my answer offended, it wasn't meant to in any way, but if you ask for _any_ advice, that may very well be what you get. If you want _specific_ advice, please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that some one can help you except you. Why? Because you have written this method and you put some logic to this method. Just ask your self Why? What? How? Where ? and etc. All these questions for your method, if you find answers you will cover your method with tests with big percentages.